# Microsoftの音声合成・音声認識（oxford-speech-api）のサンプルプログラム使用方法について

Tags: ruby

Microsoftのoxford-speech-apiを使用して英語の読み上げを計画しているプログラム初心者です。
Microsoft AzureによりPrimary KeyとSecondary Keyを取得し、サンプルを実行しましたが、
1行目の「require 'oxford-speech-api'」でエラーのようです。
原因と対策のご教授をお願いします。

■サンプルプログラム (oxford-speech-api-sample.rb)

```
require 'oxford-speech-api'
api = OxfordSpeechApi.new("clientId", "secret")
# 注) clientIdとsecretにそれぞれPrimary KeyとSecondary Key（32桁の英数字）を代入

#api.speech2text("file.wav", "audio/wav", "8000") # returns json
api.text2speech("hello world") # return wav
```

■エラーメッセージ

```
ruby oxford-speech-api-sample.rb
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in 'require': cannot load such file -- rest-client(LoadError)
from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in 'require'
from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/oxford-speech-api-0.0.1/lib/oxford-speech-api.rb:1:in '[top (required)]' 　　注）top (required)は、実際には不等号で囲まれているが表示されないため、不等号を[]に置き換えた
from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in 'require'
from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in 'rescue in require'
from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:144:in 'require'
from oxford-speech-api.rb:1:in '[main]'
```

■計算条件

```
ruby -v  : ruby 2.1.7p400 (2015-08-18 revision 51632) [i386-mingw32]
gem list : oxford-speech-api (0.0.1)
```

Windows 7 HomePremium   Service Pack1
モデル：VAIO シリーズ
プロセッサ： Pentium(R) Dual-Core CPU E6300 @2.80GHz 2.80GHz
実装メモリ(RAM)：4.00GB
システムの種類：64ビットOS

以上、よろしくお願いいたします

Answer (score 1):

`oxford-speech-api (0.0.1)`が`rest-client >= 0`と古いバージョンを指定している（最新は1.8.0）のに、新しい呼び方である`require 'rest-client'`を使っているのが原因です。
古い呼び出し方である`require 'rest_client'`に`oxford-speech-api.rb`を書き換えると動くっぽいです